# Calculating column totals and then sorting on the results in R

Tags: r

Please can anyone offer guidance on how to

1. calculate column totals and then
2. sort on the resultant totals in R?

Everything I've tried so far to total the columns, eg, (`colsums()` and `sapply()` returns the resultant totals as a vector (eg `ABOUT   4022`) and I cannot find any information on how I can split this into the Column Header `ABOUT` and Column Value `4022` and then sort both the Header and Value on the Column Value.

Comment: doesn't `sort(colSums(mat))` with `mat` being your matrix or data frame do what you want?

Comment: Please make your situation reproducible, i.e. provide us with the data and the code needed to mimic your situation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for more tips on how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the function is called `colSums` (not colsums).

Use this with `sort`. Or if you want to order the columns use `order`:

```
colSums(mtcars)
sort(colSums(mtcars))

mtcars[ ,order(colSums(mtcars))]
```